# How to access an Ubuntu server(Guest) from a Ubuntu machine(Host)?

Tags: unix, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx

I have installed Ubuntu server (10.10) using Oracle VM VirtualBox

How to access from host machine to that guest machine.

IP of host machine: ***.55.21.16

IP of guest machine: 10.0.2.15

ssh-server on the guest machine is correctly working with:

```
$ sudo netstat -lntp | grep 22
tcp6        0      0 :::22            :::*               LISTEN     3574/sshd
```

How do I connect to that host machine.

Before placing this question I tried 
http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=148 but its not working for me.

Host machine configuration (ifconfig)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:9b:45:7d:06  
          inet addr:1**.1*.99.15  Bcast:1*2.1*.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe**::221:9bf*:fe55:7d06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:323824 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:124446873 (124.4 MB)  TX bytes:8365574 (8.3 MB)
          Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7412 (7.4 KB)  TX bytes:7412 (7.4 KB)
```

Comment: Can you paste in the details of your interfaces on the host machine? The result of "sudo ifconfig" would do.

Comment: do you have any communication between the host and the guest with ping?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [network modes](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) in the virtualbox manual, it seems that the guest and the host don't have any communication.

Sometimes the default configuration ([NAT](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat)) doesn't fit with the needs, try "Host-only networking".

Have you tried the [rdp connection](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) with the guest?

Comment: No I only tried NAT

Comment: the vrdp connection it's another way to access to the vm, but i repeat... you must check that you have a connection between your guest and host, try with ping, it should work.

Comment: If i do 'ifconfig' on guest machine it shows its static ip: 10.0.2.15 If i ping from host using 'ping 10.0.2.15' it not working.

Comment: @suvankar try the [host-only network](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)  it seems that with your config (modem not router) it will be the useful.